# How to divide a number into an undefined random number of chunks, with each chunk being a random size within a min and max size?

Tags: algorithm, math, random

I'm using C# but this is more of a logic question than a language question. I'm stumped. I've found similar questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14427531/how-to-split-a-list-into-n-random-but-min-sized-chunks) but the difference being I won't know how many chunks until the last chunk is formed. The only thing I know at the start is the total number of items, and the min and max size of chunks of items.
Say I have an int totalItems = 15. I want to divide it into chunks that are a random size from 3 to 5. None of the chunks should be outside that range, and no remainder.

So some valid outcomes include:

5,5,5
3,3,3,3,3
5,4,3,3

But the problem is whenever selecting the second-to-last chunk it has to consider what will be left over for the last chunk. For instance:
If the first 3 chunks are 3,5,5 (all valid sizes) there is only 2 left, so the 3rd chunk should have been no larger than 4, so that the remainder would be no less than 3.

Here's what I've got so far which isn't working:

```cs
private List<int> SplitIntoChunks(int totalItems, int minChunkSize, int maxChunkSize)
    {
        List<int> chunks = new();

        int remainingItems = totalItems;

        while (remainingItems > 0)
        {
            int chunkSize;

            if (remainingItems == minChunkSize)
            {
                chunkSize = minChunkSize;
            }
            else
            {
                chunkSize = Random.Range(minChunkSize, Mathf.Min(maxChunkSize, remainingItems) + 1);

                if (remainingItems - chunkSize < minChunkSize)
                {
                    chunkSize = remainingItems; // This sometimes results in chunkSize larger than maxChunkSize.
                }

                if (remainingItems - chunkSize > maxChunkSize)
                {
                    chunkSize = maxChunkSize; // This then sometimes results in a remainder that is too small for the next chunk.
                }
            }

            chunks.Add(chunkSize);

            remainingItems -= chunkSize;
        }

        return chunks;
    }
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about what is entailed in each operation and the order of operations. For example, in the title you state, "How to divide a number into an undefined random number of chunks...". To me that sounds like the first step. If, as in the example, `totalItems = 15`, presumably there could be anything between 1 and 15 chunks? Later you introduce minimum and maximum sizes for each chunk of 3 and 5, meaning the number of chunks could be between 15/5 and 15/3 or 3, 4 or 5...

Comment: ...Does that mean we should randomly select 3, 4 or 5 with equal probability, even though other sampling procedures 4 chunks might be more likely than 3 or 4? When you use the word "random" it has a specific mathematical meaning; namely, that every outcome of an experiment is equally likely. You can't just waive the word around. We need to know what the equally-likely outcomes are in order to construct a method of generating them in a statistically-valid way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get random chunks until there is a remainder (if there is no you win). Say the remainder is `n<minSize`, then there is missing `minSize-n` units, so pick these units in the list of know chunks that have size `>minSize`.

Ex.: You want to split 15, and found (3,5,5;2). You then need to pick one (3-2) in one of the 5's, say (3,5,4;3).

This splitting may also be completed a little bit more to get a truly random splitting. Now that you have (3,5,4,3) you can determine which are the possible value for the last: `maxSize=5` actual remainder is `3` then you may try to pick at most 2 more units. As there is 3 units that can be transfered to the last, values at the end may be 3, 4 or 5. Pick one at random, then complete as previously. Say you randomly chose 4 to be at the end, then find a unit in (3,5,4;3), say (3,4,3;4).

You may also use another algorithm.
Roughly.
Determine that there is at least 15/5 chunks at most 15/3, chose a length (randomly or not depends on your needs), fill it with 3's and then distribute what remains **randomly**:

- possible lengths are 3, 4, 5, chose one, say 4 (if you know the length at beginning, you will then know if you can solve the problem or not)
- construct (3,3,3,3), total is 12, there is 3 units to distribute in it
- let say you chose to add one at (random chose) first position then get (4,3,3,3)
- let say you chose to add one at (random chose) fourth then get (4,3,3,4)
- chose one at random and add one, let say you chose position fourth, you then get (4,3,3,5)
  Beware not to consider positions already filled with `maxSize` at each round.

Comment: Hmm, your second algorithm is compelling! I just implemented it and it worked! The only issue is that it results in the quantity of chunks being the factor that is truly random, which results in the size of the chunks being weighted heavily toward the smaller chunks. I would love to figure out how to make it so that chunks of 5 are just as likely/common as chunks of 3, which correlates with the quantity of chunks being weighted slightly more in favor of fewer chunks.

Comment: I suppose I could fake it by changing how I randomly select a number of chunks, so that it's slightly more likely to pick a smaller number.

Comment: Pick a position at random to weight it (may be I was not so clear about this). Pick eligible positions only (the ones that are strictly less than maxSize.

Comment: Yep, I understood exactly. Thank you for the great idea! I selected your answer, and also posted my own where I take your solution and augment it to make the chunk size more uniform, rather than the chunk quantity.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this problem can be unsolvable. For example totalItems = 5, minChunkSize = 3, maxChunkSize = 4. Here the first chunk will be 3 or 4, and the second chunk must be 2 or 1, which is forbidden.

For possible inputs, one solution can be found like this. We add only the minimum size chunks, and then distribute the remainder between them. If the remainder does not fit completely, then the problem is not solvable on such inputs.

```cs
List<int> SplitIntoChunks(int totalItems, int minChunkSize, int maxChunkSize)
{
    int chunksCount = totalItems / minChunkSize;
    int remainder = totalItems % minChunkSize;

    if ((maxChunkSize - minChunkSize) * chunksCount < remainder) 
        throw new Exception("unsolvable");

    var chunks = Enumerable.Repeat(element: minChunkSize, count: chunksCount).ToList();

    for(int i = 0; i < chunksCount; ++i)
    {
        if (remainder == 0) break;

        int addition = Math.Min(maxChunkSize - minChunkSize, remainder);
        chunks[i] += addition;
        remainder -= addition;
    }

    return chunks;
}
```

Then, if you need randomness, you can randomly modify the initial solution.

Comment: The OP clearly states that randomness is required. That means that the "valid outcomes" are equally-likely to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Using [the answer by Jean-Baptiste Yunès](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78187710/2909544) as a starting point, I came up with this solution which allows you to weight the possible number of chunks so that all of the resulting possible sizes are given just as much likelihood to appear. If the total items is 15 and dividing into 3 chunks is just as likely as dividing into 5 chunks, then chunks of size 3 will appear 1.66 times more than chunks of size 5, so weighing the random selection helps make the chunk size be the equally random part of the equation. (I realize that with this particular set of parameters, chunks of size 4 will still be less likely due to all the ways 15 can be divided, so it's not perfect, but it's better.)

```cs
private List<int> SplitIntoChunks(int totalItems, int minChunkSize, int maxChunkSize)
    {
        int minChunks = Mathf.CeilToInt((float)totalItems / maxChunkSize);
        int maxChunks = Mathf.FloorToInt((float)totalItems / minChunkSize);

        int randNumChunks = GetRandomNumChunks(minChunks, maxChunks, weighted);

        int[] chunks = new int[randNumChunks];

        List<int> nonMaxedChunkIndexes = new();

        int allocatedItems = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < chunks.Length; i++)
        {
            chunks[i] = minChunkSize;

            nonMaxedChunkIndexes.Add(i);

            allocatedItems += minChunkSize;
        }

        int remainder = totalItems - allocatedItems;

        for (int i = 0; i < remainder; i++)
        {
            int rand = Random.Range(0, nonMaxedChunkIndexes.Count);

            int index = nonMaxedChunkIndexes[rand];

            chunks[index]++;

            if (chunks[index] == maxChunkSize)
            {
                nonMaxedChunkIndexes.RemoveAt(rand);
            }
        }

        return new List<int>(chunks);
    }

    private int GetRandomNumChunks(int minChunks, int maxChunks, bool weighted)
    {
        if (weighted)
        {
            List<float> weightedOdds = new();

            float cumulativeWeight = 0.0f;

            for (int i = minChunks; i <= maxChunks; i++)
            {
                float weight = (float)maxChunks / i;

                cumulativeWeight += weight;

                weightedOdds.Add(cumulativeWeight);
            }

            float rand = Random.value * cumulativeWeight;

            for (int i = 0; i < weightedOdds.Count; i++)
            {
                if (weightedOdds[i] >= rand)
                {
                    return minChunks + i;
                }
            }
        }

        return Random.Range(minChunks, maxChunks + 1);
    }
```